# belongs_to changes header in activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a model names `goods` that can have `assets`. The assets can be accessed via the sidebar:

[image: Goods Model]

For reasons I do not know does the menu change, when i enter the assets section:

[image]

I want the menu to be the same, no matter where the user is. It's my navigation bar.

Is this a bug or a feature? Can I change the behaviour?

Comment: This appears to be a bug.  I've created an issue for it https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/2739

Answer (score 7):

The solution to this I found was simple and was actually documented in [the official documentation](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/2-resource-customization.md#belongs-to). All you need to do is to add `navigagion_menu :default` to your resource.

Like so

```
ActiveAdmin.register Asset do
  menu false
  belongs_to :good
  navigation_menu :default
end
```